# Sort Elasticsearch results based on field value

Tags: elasticsearch

Assuming I have 3 documents (users), and they have knowledge of multiple programming languages - with scores associated, as described below, how can I search for multiple fields (multi-match for example), and if some search-keywords hits a language, sort by its score?

```
    // user1 
    {
        "name": "John Bayes",
        "prog_langs": [
            {
                "name": "python",
                "score": 10
            },
            {
                "name": "java",
                "score": 500
            }
        ]
    }        



    // user2 
    {
        "name": "John Russel",
        "prog_langs": [
            {
                "name": "python",
                "score": 100
            },
            {
                "name": "PHP",
                "score": 200
            }
        ]
    }        



    // user3
    {
        "name": "Terry Guy",
        "prog_langs": [
            {
                "name": "C++",
                "score": 600
            },
            {
                "name": "Javascript",
                "score": 200
            }
        ]
    }
```

For example: searching "John python"
Should return user1 and user2, but user2 showing up first

---

**I've been trying to use sort and functions, but I think they always use lowest/highest/average values of score.

Thanks!

---

[Edit]
**In the meantime I got it working in a testing way to see if without full-text/multi-matched works, and I found out I had to make "prog_langs" nested, so I changed the mapping and it works as expected.

Now I'm only missing the part where a full-text search with multi-match merges with current query.

Thanks again!

Comment: so, what isn't working now? could you share the queries that you're doing and what's wrong with them?

Comment: I will post an edit soon with the queries I have, but the thing is that if I query the prog_langs directly I can now sort only based on the ones that matched.

My goal is that, the user can type anything he wants (any field in my document is searchable), and if it is  a prog_lang, I want to sort documents by the score of the language that matched, and my last results happen to sort in a weird way (weird being a result that I don't think is correct)

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the query and decided to try a small change and I guess I achieved what I was looking for. Will post here the query for everyone if everything is working as expected!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the query and now it's working as expected.

Before posting my solution, just have to leave a few things to keep in mind:

- I made a new mapping, and added some nested objects, so my original query had to suffer some changes (prog_langs are now of type **nested**)
- I wanted at least two fields to match, being mandatory which should match at least once

---

```
    {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "query": {
                            "match": {
                                "name": {
                                    "query": "john python",
                                    "boost": 5
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "bool": {
                            "should": [
                                {
                                    "nested": {
                                        "path": "prog_langs",
                                        "query": {
                                            "match": {
                                                "prog_langs.name": {
                                                    "query": "john python",
                                                    "boost": 5
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "should": [
                    {
                        "function_score": {
                            "query": {
                                "match": {
                                    "prog_langs.name": "john python"
                                }
                            },
                            "functions": [
                                {
                                    "script_score": {
                                        "script": "_score * (1 + doc['prog_langs.score'].value)"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "highlight": {
            "fields": {
                "name": {},
                "prog_langs.name": {}
            }
        }
    }
```